# In Apache 2 how can I disable 'autocomplete' of partial web addresses?

Tags: apache2

I noticed a log entry for a page being served that doesn't exist in the DocumentRoot of my server:

mydomain.com/test/

In context, in the logs, it was obvious that '/test/' was part of a 'scan' for typical vulnerable pages. I'm not concerned by the attempt, I'm concerned that '/test/' didn't 404.

I eventually figured out that what my server was doing was SEARCHING for a partial match of the name "test" in my document root. So it found "test.jpg" and ended up serving a "page" it called "index.html", but whose contents were the image for "test.jpg".

If I had a page named "some.htm" and I entered mydomain.com/some/ in my browser I would be served a page named "index.html" which contained the contents of "some.htm".

As mentioned at the start, I was seeing the URL mydomain/test/ being requested in my logs, so this isn't a browser issue. Apache seems to have a function to search for and 'autocomplete' requests that should be 404 as typed.

Is there any way to turn this off, or at least limit the behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I did some more googling and discovered that this behavior is the result of the content negotiation feature known as "MultiViews", which activates any time a partial address is 404, but matches the name portion of a file. Ie. Apache will only 'autocomplete' addresses when the only thing missing is the file extension.

If I want to stop the behavior, I just need to disable the MultiViews option in my config.